# How to handle custom button click event for PrimeNG p-fullCalendar?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using the `p-fullCalendar` control to display appointments.

I want to add a custom button in the header to add a new appointment.

I have done that by specifying it in the options [as per full calendar docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/customButtons):

```
export class AppointmentsComponent implements OnInit {

  events: any[];
  options: any;
  displayAddAppointment: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.options = {
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'addAppointmentButton, month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      customButtons: {
        addAppointmentButton:{
          text:"New appointment",
          click: r=> {
            //this works but displayAddAppointment within the component is inaccessible.
            //I would like to display a modal dialog to add a new appointment from this.
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

the html being :

```
<div>
 <p-fullCalendar [events]="events" [options]="options"></p-fullCalendar>

 <p-dialog header="Schedule new appointment" 
         [(visible)]="displayAddAppointment" 
         modal="modal">
 </p-dialog>
<div>
```

The button is displayed fine and the click event gets fired too.

But how do I handle the click event of this button so that I can display the modal dialog?

The `this` within the click event is the button itself:

[image: thiswithinclickevent]

Comment: what does `this` refer to in the click event?

Comment: @MarkusDresch I've updated the question to answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the click event to a component method and bind(this):

```
addAppointmentButton: {
    text: 'New appointment',
    click: this.click.bind(this)
}
// ...
click() {
    this.displayAddAppointment = !this.displayAddAppointment;
}
```

Tested and works. This way you don't lose scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `_self = this` and handle with this `_self` variable

```
ngOnInit() {
    let _self = this;
    this.options = {
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'addAppointmentButton, month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      customButtons: {
        addAppointmentButton:{
          text:"New appointment",
          click: (r) => {
              console.log(_self);
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: have you tried it?
There is no difference between assigning it to the variable and accessing the variable vs accessing it directly. It's one and the same.
It doesn't work